# grails dynamic view

Tags: grails, view, scaffolding

I'm pretty new to grails. I was wondering how to dynamically generate views, like I can a controller. For example, I have domain class

```
class Student {
     String firstName
     String lastName
}

class StudentController {
     def scaffold = true
 }
```

Now I can create my views with grails generate-views, but if I add a field to Student for example, then I need to re-run that command. Is there a way to dynamically create the view (based on the default templates) if I am just using the default view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grails generate-views` is for generating a static view file that you'll then begin to tweak yourself. If you don't do `grails generate-views`, then your scaffolding for views should be created dynamically at runtime, and will reflect changes to your domain classes.

[See here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html).

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly regenerated the controller which removed my scaffolding. Now it works.